# UWP StreamSocket ConnectAsync exception 0xC00D36FF

Tags: c#, exception, stream, uwp

I'm getting a very strange exception using a UWP StreamSocket, 99.9% of the time this code functions as expected and the communication with the device works properly, however I get the following exception every once in a while.

**The exception message:**

The operation failed because an invalid combination of workqueue ID and flags was specified. (Exception from HRESULT: 0xC00D36FF)

**Sample code for the issue:**

```
using (StreamSocket analyzerSocket = new StreamSocket())
{
    HostName hostName = new HostName(host);

    // Set NoDelay to false so that the Nagle algorithm is not disabled
    analyzerSocket.Control.NoDelay = false;

    try
    {
        // Connect to the server
        await analyzerSocket.ConnectAsync(hostName, port.ToString()).AsTask(new CancellationTokenSource(_timeout).Token);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        var x = e;
    }
}
```

**Screenshot of exception in code:**
[image: Screenshot]

**The Stack Trace:**

```
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at Analyzer.<SendMessageAsync>d__120.MoveNext() in zzz.cs:line 779
```

I've tried my GoogleFu and I was able to find issues with MediaPlayer or Linux kernels but nothing seemed to relate to this issue with StreamSockets.

While I can trap this error and work around the issue I would like to know what's going on in case it's a symptom of a bigger issue.

Thanks in advance.

**Edit 1**

I thought this might be related to http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs,be57b6bc41e5c7e4 based on the code comment of "// And throw an exception if the task is faulted or canceled.".

However I still get this expcetion when I am not using the ".AsTask(new CancellationTokenSource(timeout.Value).Token)"

**Edit 2**

When I have this in a loop, to constantly send messages to our device, the messages are being received until this exception occurs.  Once the exception occurs and I tell it to continue and try again, the exception re-occurs over and over in the loop and the device stops receiving messages.

**Edit 3**

So I've tried the following, to connect to a different device, with a different instance of the StreamSocket object... and it generates the same error!

```
using (StreamSocket analyzerSocket = new StreamSocket())
{
    HostName hostName = new HostName(host);

    // Set NoDelay to false so that the Nagle algorithm is not disabled
    analyzerSocket.Control.NoDelay = false;

    try
    {
        // Connect to the server
        await analyzerSocket.ConnectAsync(hostName, port.ToString()).AsTask(new CancellationTokenSource(_timeout).Token);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        using (StreamSocket analyzerSocket2 = new StreamSocket())
        {
            HostName hostName2 = new HostName("xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx");

            // Set NoDelay to false so that the Nagle algorithm is not disabled
            analyzerSocket.Control.NoDelay = false;

            // Connect to the server
            await analyzerSocket2.ConnectAsync(hostName2, port.ToString());
        }

        throw;
    }
}
```

It feels like some sort of cross threading type of issue... I'm grasping at straws right now as I cannot trap and bypass the error as once the error occurs I can no longer talk to the devices and I must exit the application to get it to work again.

Does anyone have any other ideas or confirmation that it looks like cross threading type of issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The SocketError.GetStatus method can be used to convert a network error from a socket operation to a [SocketErrorStatus enumeration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/hh701457?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) value. You can try to get the error status and handle this exception specifically.

Comment: @GraceFeng-MSFT Thank you for the idea, however in my case the SocketError.GetStatus returned "Unknown".  I'm leaning towards http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs,be57b6bc41e5c7e4 being the issue based on this comment "// And throw an exception if the task is faulted or canceled."...

Comment: That is MF_E_INVALID_WORKQUEUE. an error code that is only produced by Media Foundation.  The Windows component that supports media playback.  The stack trace of the exception is poor but the odds that it has anything to do with a network error ought to be zero.

Comment: @HansPassant Yes, I saw that as well, however when I turn on extensive error throwing, basically stop on anything, it is most certainly throwing the exception on the .ConnectAscync method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I have found to prevent this issue is to stop using the "StreamSocket" altogether.

I switched my code to use the "System.Net.Sockets" namespace using the Socket object instead and with some modifications to my code I haven't encountered this issue since.

**Code sample:**

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh202858%28v=vs.105%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396