# UWP StreamSocket ConnectAsync 'Invalid combination of workqueue ID'

Tags: c#, sockets, uwp

I'm running into this unexpected error and unfortunately have not found anything on this around that solves or identifies this issue. Does anyone know anything about this?

The error returned is

> "System.Exception: The operation failed because an invalid combination
>   of workqueue ID and flags was specified. (Excep_FromHResult
>   0xC00D36FF)"

Code follows this template:

```
  using (socket = new StreamSocket())
  {
    var hostName = new HostName(server);
    socket.Control.NoDelay = false;

    try
    {
        await _socket.ConnectAsync(hostName, port, SocketProtectionLevel.PlainSocket);              
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // Handle Exception
    }
  }
```

Comment: It looks like you have a "Connect Async" method  : See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.socket.connectasync?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: I realize that. The question is asking if anyone has seen this exception, it is not documented by Microsoft it seems. The link to the method being used is this one https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.networking.sockets.streamsocket.connectasync#Windows_Networking_Sockets_StreamSocket_ConnectAsync_Windows_Networking_HostName_System_String_Windows_Networking_Sockets_SocketProtectionLevel_

Comment: The error isn't coming from c# it is coming from Windows dll.  I checked the c# Reference Source code and did not find any results.  Then found the windows enumeration associated with the error : INVALID_WORK_QUEUE_ITEM.  You can search web to find answers.  See following : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39711444/uwp-streamsocket-connectasync-exception-0xc00d36ff